# Saving data between widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter

hi  i am making an app for restaurant but  i need some help i have a listtilel and i would like to save those values in memory or firebase anywhere i would like to get  which topics selected  how should i do that 
basicly i meant i want to get choosen datas from user  and i would like to add it orders  page if you have any suggestions please let me know thanks

[image: this is screen of food details]

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:resat/BurgerListView/data/toppics_model.dart';
  import 'data/toppics.dart';

 class decor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
  return new MyAppState();
   }
   }


 class MyAppState extends State<decor> {

 List ketchup = [
'No',
'light',
'regular',
'extra',
   ];
       List calori = ['0 Cal', '1 Cal', '2 Cal', '3 Cal'];
       var i = 2;


    final List<topics> _topics = categories;

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build

return Container(

    margin: EdgeInsets.all(6), //space between other listtiles
    decoration: BoxDecoration(

        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),

    child: ListTile(

        title: Row(children: [
          Expanded(
              child:
              Text("Ketchup\n" + calori[i], textAlign: TextAlign.center,),),
          Expanded(
            child: (InkWell(
              child: Text("-", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (i <= 0){
                    i = i;
                  }else
                    i--;
                  print(i);
                });
              },
            )),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Text(ketchup[i], textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
          Expanded(
            child: (InkWell(
              child: Text("+", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (i > 2) {
                    i = i;
                  } else
                    i++;
                  print(i);
                });
              },
            )),
          ),

        ]),

        leading: Icon(Icons.pie_chart))
);
  }
 }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences - You can use this to save values locally on your device.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you two ways to save your data across the different users.

Unsurprisingly it's an online database either via firebase or vis your own Web service APIs hosted on your server.

I don't suggest you offline database(SQLite) anyway because it will be limited to a single user.

The data you save and fetch will be limited to a single user.

So, try learning the flutter concepts from,

[Firebase database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfA3NWDBPZ4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC)

[Web api implementation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

[Offline datbase](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)